# Counting word problem

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following word problem while studying for the GREs.

> There are five employees willing to serve on two different committees, each of which has one opening. If each selected employee can only serve on one committee, how many possible ways are there for the openings on the committees to be filled?

It seems to me that there are two ways to look at this problem. 
The first is that we have 5 choices for the first committee and 4 choices for the second committee so our total options are 5x4=20.

We can also view this as a choose problem where we need to select 2 people from our 5 available to assign to committees where order doesn't matter so we get 5 choose 2 = 10.

Why do the two different views give different answers when both seem correct?

Comment: Because each of the $10$ pairs can be assigned to the two committees in two different ways.

Comment: We should assume the two committees are distinct, so there would be 20 options.

Comment: Order _does_ matter, the committees are distinct.

Comment: What is an easy litmus test for figuring out when order matters?

Comment: I guess thinking about given two people is assigning Bob to committee 1 and fred to committee 2 the same as Bob to committee 2 and Fred to committee 1 ?